# awk condition not working

Tags: awk

I have a command below but it does not output anything. If I retain the `print $0` or any column (e.g `print $2`, `print $3`) it will print as it should. It seems that it does not read the "if statement".

```
awk -F"," '{if ($2 >= 09170000000 && $2 <= 09179999999) print $0 }' filename
```

Sample file:

```
"dummy","09171234567","","dummy","dummy","dummy","dummy"
```

Comment: Missing `;` before print

Comment: it will print all lines

Comment: @val0x00ff No, that's not the issue, please see my answer below

Comment: @αғsнιη It indeed isn't `;` I quickly overlooked that and ignored the Field Delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are telling `awk` to read the data as comma delimited, the quotes will be part of the data and the integer comparisons will fail:

```
$ awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' file.txt
"09171234567"
```

Instead, allow for the comma to be surrounded by quotes:

```
$ awk -F'"?,"?' '{ print $2 }' file.txt
09171234567
```

The expression `"?,"?` means "a comma, with optional double quotes before and/or after".

The final `awk` code:

```
$ awk -F'"?,"?' '$2 >= 09170000000 && $2 <= 09179999999' file.txt
"dummy","09171234567","","dummy","dummy","dummy","dummy"
```

A condition with no `{...}` block will output the current input line if it evaluates to true.

Comment: @user257133 Good! I'm slightly confused why αғsнιη's solution did not work for you though. It worked for me on OpenBSD using both GNU `awk` and the native BSD `awk`...

Comment: @Kusalananda that's because column order is being change in my answer and you know, but OP sounds doesn't aware of this, and s/he was trying with same `$2` with `[",]` as delims.

Comment: @αғsнιη Sounds likely.

Comment: @ sorry my bad, I was so confused with column position that I was still following $2. Thank you for the answer, it worked as well :) . Now, I understand what you really meant after the update.

Answer (score 4):

Because your column#2 is a text when it's in quote `"..."`, and you are doing integer comparison. Do it as follow to define `"` as one of delimiters and then compare on column5 which based on both `,` and `"` now it's column#5 :

```
awk -F'[",]' '{if ($5>= 09170000000 && $5 <= 09179999999) print $0 }' infile
```

Or in short:

```
awk -F'[",]' '$5>= 09170000000 && $5 <= 09179999999' infile
```

When we used two `,` and `"` delimiters your columns number will be in `(col#*3)-1` position now, means if it was in column `$30` before, now it's in column `$89`.

Comment: still no output

Comment: please see my update